# Proving that $\sum \frac{n^{n+1/n}}{(n+1/n)^n}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that the series 
$$\sum \frac{n^{n+1/n}}{(n+1/n)^n}$$ diverges

The ratio test is inconclusive and this limit is not easy to calculate. So I've tried the comparison test without success.

Comment: Calculate the limit of the $n$th term.

Comment: Can you try it? It is not easy!

Comment: Indeed, Jyrki! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this way's clearer:
$$\frac{n^{n+1/n}}{\left(n+1/n\right)^n}=\frac{\sqrt[n]n}{\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n}$$

Comment: Yes, I found this know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here cancelling a factor $n^n$ works:
$$
\frac{n^{n+1/n}}{(n+1/n)^n}=\frac{n^{1/n}}{(1+\frac1{n^2})^n}\to\frac11=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$ \frac{n^{n+1/n}}{(n+1/n)^n}=\frac{n^{1/n}}{(1+1/n^2)^n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1\ne0$$
so the series is divergent.

Comment: I edited the question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof without using $\lim_{n \to \infty}{(1+1/n^2)^n}=1 $:

$$\frac{n^{n+1/n}}{\left(n+1/n\right)^n} \ge \frac{n^{n+1/n}}{\left(n+1\right)^n}=\frac{n^{1/n}}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}=\frac{n^{1/n}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{e}\ne0$$